# GWT property with is-multi-valued already defined

Tags: gwt

While migrating from GWT 2.7.0 to 2.8.2 I came upon property:

```
<define-configuration-property name="CssResource.gssDefaultInUiBinder"
    is-multi-valued="true" />
```

If this is left as it is, I get an error: `The configuration property named CssResource.gssDefaultInUiBinder is already defined with a different 'is-multi-valued' setting`.

Does that mean that I can't set attribute `is-multi-valued` to already defined property? Why would this work with GWT 2.7.0 then? Can anyone give me an explanation about this attribute? Because I am failing to find one...

Attribute set in GWT resources:

```
<!-- The default for GSS in UiBinder -->
<define-configuration-property name="CssResource.gssDefaultInUiBinder" is-multi-valued="false" />
```

[gwt/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/Resources.gwt.xml](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/Resources.gwt.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct - you should not be trying to change `is-multi-valued`, it doesn't really make any sense. You can't re-define a property or configuration-property after it has been set, you can only set the value.

If you want to turn the gss-in-ui-binder flag on, use this:

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.gssDefaultInUiBinder" value="true" />
```

If you want to turn it off, either do nothing, or do this:

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.gssDefaultInUiBinder" value="false" />
```

Comment: What does this attribute actually do? Why would this work with 2.7  version?  (I have not checked myself, but maybe 2.7 did not have this attribute set by default?)

Comment: GWT 2.7 version does not have CssResource.gssDefaultInUiBinder variable defined, that's why it worked.

Comment: CssResource has undergone a change, see http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_0_BETA1 and http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/gss_migration.html - the short version is that this flag lets you indicate that you haven't yet migrated your uibinder style. Once you update it, remove the flag.